# recursion $t(n)=\sqrt{2} \times \frac{tn}{2} +\log{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

I tried substituting $m=\log{n}$

$t(2^n)=\sqrt{2} \times \frac{t2^n}{2}+m t(m)= \sqrt(2) \times \frac{tm}{2}+m$

From here I got  $\log {n}$ But with induction I proofed its $\sqrt {n}$

Comment: Do you really sure that your edit is correct?

Comment: in your righthandside is $\frac{t2^n}{2} = \frac{t(2^n)}{2}$ or is it a multiplication?

Comment: Its t((2^n)\2)    after m=log(n)

Comment: Its t((2^n)\2) after i sub m=lon(n)

Comment: Is this $t(n) =  \sqrt{2} \cdot t(n / 2) + \log n$ or something else? It is very confusing as written.